# Apache Superset - How to change label color in JSON metadata for Hindi text

Tags: apache-superset

In Apache superset we can change label colors, to do that, have your dashboard on edit mode, press the 3 dots and choose Edit Properties. Look in the advanced option which contains JSON metadata, and add your labels

`"label_colors":{ " Girls":"#FF69B4", "Boys":"#ADD8E6" }`

But Superset is not allowing us to work with languages like Hindi to be populated for label_colors, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Eg:

`"label_colors":{  "लड़कियाँ":"#FF69B4",  "लड़के":"#ADD8E6"  }`

Any help is greatly appreciated

Tried adding hindi text in JSON metadata, but it didnt save the dashboard